# C language modulus not showing right answer when tested against large number

Tags: c

This program

```
long a = 20202020200;
b = (a / 100) % 10;

printf("%d", b);
```

prints "5" instead of printing "2". Why is that?

Comment: It prints `2` for me.

Comment: What is `sizeof(long)` on your system?

Comment: Please post a [mcve] and tell us which system and compiler you are using. Most importantly, what is `sizeof(long)`/`LONG_MAX` on your system?

Comment: Notably 20202020200 = 20.20*10^9 so it won't fit in a 32 bit number. On a 32 bit system, the conversion from 64 bit to 32 bit will be implementation-defined.

Comment: Also, on Windows 64-bit `long` is still 32-bit while it is 64-bit on Linux. Use `int64_t` for cross-platform 64-bit numbers.

Comment: What type is `b`?

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the Binary `20202020200  = ‭0100_1011_0100_0010_0010_0101_1101_0110_1000‬`

Which is 36 bit.

So if you have a 32-bit system you will have `1011_0100_0010_0010_0101_1101_0110_1000‬` or ‭`0100_1011_0100_0010_0010_0101_1101_0110`.

In your case, it is the second one that represents `315656565 /100 = 3156565 % 10 = 5`